Можно ли стилизовать или заменить на кастомные элементы управления ymaps3 (reactify)?
С добавлением кастомной панели управления и работой с состоянием карты проблем нет. Хотелось бы узнать можно ли стилизовать или заменить своими компонентами исходные элементы управления картой (зум, геолокация)?

Штатные элементы управления не подлежат кастомизации. Если вам нужны элементы в своём стиле, их следует собирать самостоятельно.
Например, свой контрол геолокации можно собрать по примеру с кнопкой полноэкранной карты из ymaps3.geolocation.getPosition()
